# Perhaps a missing \item?

Tags: enumitem

I tried to reduce the size between lists using the `enumitem` package and I got an error saying `perhaps missing an \item`. This is my code below where I am clearly not missing it!

```
    \begin{description}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex][topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex]
    \item{(i)}  $xSx$ does not hold for all $x\in X$ (irreflexive).
    \item{(ii)}  For all $x,y\in X$, $xSy$ and $ySz$ implies $xSz$ (transitive).
    \end{description}
```

Comment: The syntax is `\begin{description}[...]`, not `\begin{description}[...][...]`.

Answer (score 3):

You had duplicate the options `[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex]` to description:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex]
    \item{(i)}  $xSx$ does not hold for all $x\in X$ (irreflexive).
    \item{(ii)}  For all $x,y\in X$, $xSy$ and $ySz$ implies $xSz$ (transitive).
\end{description} 

\end{document}
```

By the way, why don't you use an `enumerate` to produce your enumerated list? Using the option `label=(\roman*)` to get the desired labelling format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex,label=(\roman*)]
    \item  $xSx$ does not hold for all $x\in X$ (irreflexive).
    \item  For all $x,y\in X$, $xSy$ and $ySz$ implies $xSz$ (transitive).
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't enumerate give it 1,2,3,...? I want to have roman numerals.

Comment: @Eduardo Did you compile my second example? It gives your roman numerals. That's what the `label` option does.